# how can I add display.movieclip(include as3 inside and embedded video, means lots of video frames) to starling?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I created a movieclip, I imported a video inside it ,as3 code that loads an image, and animate that image on the video.I use as3 codes like below

```
 import flash.filesystem.File;
 import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
 import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

 var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();  
 imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("imagem.jpeg").url));  
 imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,imageLoaded1);
```

because of performence issues, I choose Starling to record that movieclip. and I use below code for that,

```
var kmcv2:mcv2 = new mcv2();
kmcv2.x=304;
kmcv2.y=208;
kmcv2.width=750;
kmcv2.height=382;
        Starling.current.nativeOverlay.addChild(kmcv2);
```

but this code does not record it, because my movieclip is on the top.

```
      stage.drawToBitmapData( _bmp );
```

how can I handle it?

thank you.

Comment: I think you need to display that video in a **Starling** way as well, something like that: https://feathersui.com/learn/as3-starling/video-player/

Comment: Hi Organis, Thank you for your interest.you mean that, this video player plays my movie clip ( video is embedded inside frame by frame) ?

Comment: I mean, that **Stage3D** (that is controlled by **Starling**) is always behind the regular **Stage**. It was a correct decision to use **Starling** for performance benefits, but **Starling** does not work with regular **Stage** (which is why it has these benefits in the first place). That means, that you need to display everything you want to screen-capture as a part of **Starling** display hierarchy. That, in turn, means, you should not import video into the Library, but rather figure the way to employ the video player native to **Starling**.

Comment: hello Organis, thanks, again. I added video player, and I captured it, no problem about it. But my action script code and animation(animation= uploaded face image follows a path and animation according to video). How can I solve that, adding .swf (flash.display swf )file to Starling is possible?

Comment: I think you should not add to the *nativeOverlay* of starling but to *Starling.current.stage*